# MkPolygon: Display popup bubble on tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

I have a set of mkpolygons that have been added to a Map View.

- I would like to display a popup (callout) when the user taps on any of the polygons. The popup should be displayed at the location of the tap.
- I would like the bubble to look the same as when a user clicks on a pin annotation, like in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Art/bullseye_view.jpg (although I do not want to display any pin or icon on top of the polygons).
- Displaying just the title and subtitle of the mkpolygon in the bubble is fine for now.

My question is: How to do that?

Reading around, it seems this can be decomposed into 2 steps:

- first, detecting that a mkpolygon had been tapped with a gesture recognizer (as in: http://jona.than.biz/blog/detecting-touches-on-mkoverlayview/ ; but it does not seem very efficient)
- then, displaying the popup (I am not sure how to do that without also displaying a pin)

However I am fuzzy on the details...

(Sorry if this is trivial: I am just starting with iOS development and MapKit)

Thanks for your help.

Gestra

Answer (score -2):

To automatically get the popup bubble (callout view) you have to add MKAnnotations to your mapView. You can customize the appearance of the Annotations in

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

by returning a custom instance of MKAnnotationView.

A second option would be to re-create UICalloutView yourself and display it when you detect a tap (with the UIGestureRecognizer as described in the link), a possible (not tested) implementation can be found here: http://www.eidac.de/?p=183